# Error while Checking the KMS service count using Nsclient

Tags: nagios, nrpe, nsclient++

I'm getting following error.

NSClient version: 0.5.0.65 2016-11-13

**nsclient.ini:**

[/modules]

CheckWMI = enabled

**Syntax:**

./check_nrpe -H 10.122.33.96 -c check_wmi -a "query=Select * from SoftwareLicensingService" "critical=15" "warning=25" Check:KMSCurrentCount=KeyManagementServiceCurrentCount

**Output :**

UNKNOWN
Invalid command line: unrecognised option 'Check'

---

NSClient version: 0.5.0.65 2016-11-13